# Stroke and Fill not working together - ObjectiveC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a shape that I am drawing in the drawRect method of a UIView.

This is the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor brownColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 342.0 * (M_PI / 180), 90.0 * (M_PI / 180), 1);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Only the first function (between the fill and stroke) works.

If I stroke first, the fill doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: post some image what you want to do exact  :)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. So, I cant post an image. Sorry, @Rushabh

Comment: @Noah: You are welcome. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: so upload in another site  and give me URL:)

Comment: It gave me an idea of what I should do. I am searching on how to use CGContextDrawPath(). It needs two arguments but the answer on the other link only tells one. :-(

Comment: Remove `CGContextFillPath(context);` and `CGContextStrokePath(context);`, add `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);`.

Comment: I'm sorry for being stupid. The other one is obviously the context.

Comment: Also here: [CoreGraphics FillPath And Stroke Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397072/coregraphics-fillpath-and-stroke-path).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you set two FillColor ?
What you want is the CGContextDrawPath() function instead of calling both CGContextFillPath() and CGContextStrokePath.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor brownColor] CGColor]);
CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 342.0 * (M_PI / 180), 90.0 * (M_PI / 180), 1);
//    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```